# Верны ли знаки препинания в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

«Анализ ценообразования в тепловых компаниях показал, что их цель – не греть людей за деньги, а нагреть людей на деньги.»

Comment: Чтобы получить развернутый ответ, пожалуйста, изложите Ваши сомнения.

Comment: Мой внутренний граммар-наци говорит, что все отлично формально и восхищается текстом и уровнем владения языком у автора. Обоснуя не будет: "Я такъ вижу!"

Comment: я думала, что после цели нужна запятая...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, знаки препинания расставлены правильно.
Почему после слова *цель* стоит тире?
См. "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" на Грамоте:
[§ 165](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire). Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если подлежащее выражено формой именительного падежа существительного, а сказуемое неопределенной формой..., например: 
Назначение каждого человека – развить в себе все человеческое, общее и насладиться им.